# Mysql process fincancial trnsaction if senders account has sufficient funds, otherwise throw error

Tags: mysql

I have the following setup: I have a table users with a username and a balance. Users can submit transactions which will allow them to send funds to other accounts. In order to do this, I need an atomic way to

- check if the senders funds cover the transaction amount
- reduce their balance by the amount
- increase the receivers balance by the amount

I need to know whether or not the transaction succeeded so I can return a response to the user. It would also need to happen in a single query, so atomicity is guaranteed. I am aware I could use transactions for this, but the problem is that would require multiple queries to a distant SQL server and would presumably also lock the entire table until its done. So I would like to simply create a single query that would do it all in one go.

I know that theres conditional queries, they don't throw exceptions if they don't succeed.

Comment: Maybe see about transactions

Comment: I specified why transactions are not a good option. They tend to lock the entire table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly it can be like this

```
update users
set balance = case when username = 'user giving' 
                   then balance - 1000
                   else balance + 1000
              end
where username in ('user giving', 'user receiving')
and exists
(
  select 1 from users where username = 'user giving' and balance >= 1000
)
```

Comment: how will I know if the transaction went through? I don't think this throws an error if the balance is too low

Comment: You can check the updated rows count. If zero it did not went through